# Creating a local branch, how to push to repository?

Tags: git

I created a local branch that contains my 'current-release' branch, how can I push this to the repository?

Comment: The sequence usually is: create a local branch, commit, then push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin remote-repository-name
```

assuming that you are on the *current-release* branch and the remote repository stuff is [properly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619117/git-push-origin-master) on your system already.

Comment: I do *git push origin develop* to send my local commits to a remote repository to a branch named *develop*.