# git push heroku origin ~ fatal: No path specified

Tags: git, heroku

I am following this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-sample_app_setup and I successfully completed all steps (git commit and push on github, heroku login and heroku app creation) until this command:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I also tried:

```
$ git push heroku origin
$ git push heroku
```

And it resulted in this error:

```
> fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
```

I tried to solve it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627029/2418066) but it didn't work for me.

After I tried what the top answer suggested, this is my config file in .git:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/kunokdev/sample_app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/test774.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Any ideas what the problem is? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

```
$ git config --list | grep heroku

url.ssh://git@heroku.com.insteadof=https://git.heroku.com/
remote.heroku.url=https://git.heroku.com/test774.git
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Comment: Try "git push heroku master"

Comment: @AkramFares same error.

Comment: What this command "git fetch --all --tags" return ?

Comment: @AkramFares OUTPUT:  `Fetching heroku` NEXT LINE
`fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax` NEXT LINE
`error: Could not fetch heroku` NEXT LINE
`Fetching origin`

Comment: "fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax" This tells you the git-pull is failing. To narrow down the problem, try doing a git pull master from your command line, to see if it fails locally. Be careful: "Because pull performs a merge on the retrieved changes, you should ensure that your local work is committed before running the pull command."

Comment: `git pull` -> Already up-to-date.
`git pull origin` -> Already up-to-date.
`git pull master` -> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: it seems the origin dosen't exist. Run this 'git remote show heroku' to show u the current origin of your app

Comment: @philipoghenerobobalogun Check screenshot for the output: http://i.imgur.com/JYlX8mm.png

Comment: Did you try heroku's ssh remote?

Comment: change your current remote uri to `git@heroku.com:test774.git`

Comment: You can use this command `git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:test774.git`

Comment: based on the answer you referenced in your question the solution was for origin try the same thing for heroku. use `git remote rm heroku` and `git remote add heroku 'https://git.heroku.com/test774.git'` notice the url path is in quotes. Try pulling and pushing again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem so I am sharing solution here. So these are the steps from 0 to deploy:

```
$ cd path/to/dir
$ git init
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Initialized"
$ heroku login
$ heroku create appname
$ heroku git:remote -a appname
$ git remote -v
```

At this point, we can see  the problem. For some strange reason heroku generated invalid URL. As you can see in the output: (Note: I used `kunokdev` as app name)

```
heroku  ssh://git@heroku.comkunokdev.git (fetch)
heroku  ssh://git@heroku.comkunokdev.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/kunokdev/kunokdev.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/kunokdev/kunokdev.git (push)
```

Do you see the first two lines? It has ...`heroku.comkunokdev.git` instead of `heroku.com/kunokdev.git` As one good man in Ruby On Rails group suggested; To fix this, I needed to remove remote and add modified one like this:

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ git remote add heroku ssh://git@heroku.com/kunokdev.git
```

At this point when you use `$ git push heroku master` there should be no error related to invalid path url.

Comment: Really you should use git remote set-url. Instead of the add and delete

Answer (score 0):

Rather obvious, but you could have skipped this line.

```
heroku git:remote -a appname
```

Then do what you did here.

```
git remote add heroku ssh://git@heroku.com/kunokdev.git
```

`git remote add name_of_remote` is a standard git command so no need to use heroku CLI for that part.

The convention for `git push` is

```
git push name_of_remote_repo name_of_local_branch
```

If you're going to learn rails development you might as well do some basic reading or course on GIT.  You can learn the fundamentals in a matter of hrs.  https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git

Answer (score -1):

Did you do the step to create the app at heroku?
$ heroku create #some-name-you-choose

Did you go to your heroku account and check to see if the path was created?

Comment: Yes I did both successfully.